# Acceder desde PHP normal a una función de CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con mi sitio web hecho con CodeIgniter y PHP sin framework, tengo la siguiente estructura de archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la carpeta inertent-dedicado tengo un archivo index.php y se visualiza correctamente, esta página esta fuera del framework por lo tanto la base_url no funciona, ahora mi duda es como accedo a una función de mi controlador pero accediendo sin la base_url y con Ajax.

> Normalmente con la base_url se accede de la siguiente forma:

```js
                                            url: "<?php echo base_url('Abacom/ajax_send_form'); ?>",
```

> Pero ahora sin la base_url como accedo a esa función del controlador
>   Abacom?

Esto es lo que tengo pero no funciono

```js
 url: "../application/controllers/Abacom/ajax_send_form"
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Si sé que es framework, solo que tengo algunas partes donde no utilizo el framework como es la carpeta internet-dedicado, no utilizo base_url accedo pasando por las rutas utilizando ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hace falta que definas el base_url para tus peticiones AJAX solo pon la ruta de tu controlador por ejemplo:

```
url: '/Abacom/ajax_send_form'
```

en automatico sabra que debera buscar esa ruta en el dominio actual.

Comment: deja pruebo, un momento por favor...

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya salio